# Best way to match object from a constructor

Tags: javascript, jestjs

We are using Jest testing library. I am quite new to it and I have the following issue. If you want to test an object, where I'd normally use [toStrictEqual](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tostrictequalvalue). But

> Object types are checked to be equal. e.g. A class instance with fields a and b will not equal a literal object with fields a and b.

In this case my object comes from a constructor other than Object. So I can not use `expect(myObj).toStrictEqual({...})`. I'd also not use `toMatchObject` it doesn't seem a good choice (I need to test that it stores the exact same properties and not a subset.)

I tried to use `expect(myObj).toEqual({...})` but it warns me "prefer `stricEquality`".

This is what I currently run:

```
test('myTest', () => {
  expect(new OurConstructor(255)).toEqual({
    a: true,
    b: true,
    c: true,
   });
});
```

What do you think would be the most reasonable approach here? (My current code just ignores that warning.)

Comment: _"it doesn't seem a good choice"_ - why? https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tomatchobjectobject

Comment: @evolutionxbox added explanation. But it is bc I need to show that the object is exactly the same and not a subset.

Comment: https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tostrictequalvalue seems to fit your needs. Still not sure why you cannot use it?

Comment: @evolutionxbox can you read the post? It is included and I explain why it is not useful here.

Comment: Their example contradicts the post. `expect(new LaCroix('lemon')).toEqual({flavor: 'lemon'});`

Comment: @evolutionxbox that is `toEqual` mate, not `toStrictEqual`

Comment: Ha. Then it seems you've chosen the recommended one.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to shallow copy the returned object:

```
  const instance = new myConstructor(255)
  expect({...instance}).toStrictEqual({...})
```

If it is necessary we can check using [toBeInstanceOf](https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tobeinstanceofclass)

If you can ignore the rule that is also a possibility.

Comment: It's the best if it works and does what you want.

Comment: I think now it is the best that could be expected. But seems a limitation of the rule rather than from jest.